# ¿Cómo obtener el valor de un MaterialDatePicker en un TextInputEditText?

Tags: java, android-studio, material-design

Hola a todos tengo una consulta y es la siguiente:

Estoy trabajando con el componente `MaterialDatePicker` de `Material Design` y he realizado un método que al seleccionar una fecha se muestre en un `TextInputEditText` pero ello en el emulador funciona bien, pero cuando lo pruebo en el celular no muestra la fecha seleccionada en el `TextInputEditText`.

```
@Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        switch (view.getId()){
            case R.id.txtFechaDia1:
                cargarDatePickerDia(txtFechaDia1);
                break;
        }
    }
```

Este Método carga el MaterialDatePicker y lo muestra en el TextInputEditText

```
private void cargarDatePickerDia(final TextInputEditText campoFecha){
        Utilidades.cambiarIdioma(this);

        MaterialDatePicker.Builder builder = MaterialDatePicker.Builder.datePicker();
        builder.setTitleText("Seleccionar Fecha");
        final MaterialDatePicker materialDatePicker = builder.build();

        materialDatePicker.show(getSupportFragmentManager(),"DATE_PICKER");
        materialDatePicker.addOnPositiveButtonClickListener(new MaterialPickerOnPositiveButtonClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onPositiveButtonClick(Object selection) {
                Locale locale = new Locale("ES");
                String inputFormat = "dd MMM yyyy";
                String outputFormat = "dd/MM/yyyy";

                String inputDate = materialDatePicker.getHeaderText();
                String outputDate = inputDate;

                try {
                    outputDate = new SimpleDateFormat(outputFormat,locale).format(
                            new SimpleDateFormat(inputFormat,locale).parse(inputDate));
                }catch (Exception e){
                    System.out.println("formateDateFromString(): "+e.getMessage());
                    outputDate="";
                }
                campoFecha.setText(outputDate);
            }
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
private void cargarDatePickerDia(final TextInputEditText campoFecha){
        MaterialDatePicker.Builder<Long> builder = MaterialDatePicker.Builder.datePicker();
        builder.setTitleText("Seleccionar Fecha");
        MaterialDatePicker<Long> materialDatePicker = builder.build();

        materialDatePicker.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), "DATE_PICKER");
        materialDatePicker.addOnPositiveButtonClickListener(new MaterialPickerOnPositiveButtonClickListener<Long>() {

            @Override
            public void onPositiveButtonClick(Long selection) {
                // Obtiene la diferencia entre la fecha local y la fecha UTC.
                TimeZone timeZoneUTC = TimeZone.getDefault();
                // el offset es negativo, por eso el -1
                int offsetFromUTC = timeZoneUTC.getOffset(new Date().getTime()) * -1;
                Date date = new Date(selection + offsetFromUTC);
                DateFormat format =new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy",Locale.getDefault());
                String localDate=format.format(date);
                campoFecha.setText(localDate);
            }
        });
    }
```

Si quieres separar ese metodo de tu Activity, pasalo a otra clase y agrega el FragmentManager como parametro

```
public class DatePickerManager {
    public void cargarDatePickerDia(FragmentManager manager,final TextInputEditText campoFecha){
        MaterialDatePicker.Builder<Long> builder = MaterialDatePicker.Builder.datePicker();
        builder.setTitleText("Seleccionar Fecha");
        MaterialDatePicker<Long> materialDatePicker = builder.build();

        materialDatePicker.show(manager, "DATE_PICKER");
        materialDatePicker.addOnPositiveButtonClickListener(new MaterialPickerOnPositiveButtonClickListener<Long>() {

            @Override
            public void onPositiveButtonClick(Long selection) {
                // Obtiene la diferencia entre la fecha local y la fecha UTC.
                TimeZone timeZoneUTC = TimeZone.getDefault();
                // el offset es negativo, por eso el -1
                int offsetFromUTC = timeZoneUTC.getOffset(new Date().getTime()) * -1;
                Date date = new Date(selection + offsetFromUTC);
                DateFormat format =new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy", Locale.getDefault());
                String localDate=format.format(date);
                campoFecha.setText(localDate);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Si tu DatePicker va a actualizar varios textFields del mismo activity, te recomiendo mantener una instancia de DatePickerManager

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {

    private TextInputEditText campoFecha;
    private DatePickerManager datePickerManager;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        datePickerManager=new DatePickerManager();
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        campoFecha =findViewById(R.id.text);
        campoFecha.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_NULL);
        campoFecha.setOnClickListener(this);
    }



    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        datePickerManager.cargarDatePickerDia(getSupportFragmentManager(),campoFecha);

    }
}
```

Comment: Yo había creado un método para cargar MaterialDatepicker ya que lo debo usar en varios TextInputEditText.Por ello no lo hize de esa forma como lo has hecho tu.Seria mucho codigo por cada TextInputEditText que tenga.

Comment: Ya lo edite para que puedas llamarlo sin problemas

Comment: Perfecto, muchas gracias. Solo una duda si el método cargarDatePickerDia() lo paso a una  clase que valor le pasaria en getSupportFragmentManager.

Comment: Obten el Fragment Manager en tu activity y pasalo a tu objeto en el constructor o en un setter:  FragmentManager manager=getSupportFragmentManager()

Comment: Agrega una explicación del código @danms07 , te aseguro sería de ayuda a más personas en la comunidad, saludos!

Comment: Claro @Jorgesys, solo una pregunta, lo agrego como otra respuesta o los comentarios tambien admiten codigo?

Comment: @danms07 lo recomendable es agregar la explicación en el cuerpo de la respuesta, te aseguro que a varios miembros de la comunidad les sería de ayuda tu respuesta!.